# [Error:call: argument of type {context,fn} has undefined or null `fn`]

Tags: react-native, redux, reduce, redux-saga, saga

I'm using saga redux in my application, and I'm getting the following error when I try to make a request to my api the error is:

```
èrro [Error:call: argument of type {context,fn} has undefined or null `fn`] -- > and 
 << -- --> Possible unhandled Promise rejection (id:0).
```

```js
try {
  const date = yield call(cloudfy.requestExtractList(), {
    DadosConta,
  });

  console.log('test', date);
  yield put(ActionCreators.requestExtractList(response.data));
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Fires error response if I remove the () at requestExtractList
`const date = yield call(cloudfy.requestExtractList, { DadosConta, })`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if `requestExtractList` needs the `cloudfy` context, if so try:

```js
const date = yield call([cloudfy, cloudfy.requestExtractList], { DadosConta, })
```

If you again get an error reponse it means the problem is in the data you send to the endpoint, not the saga api.

Additionally, if you are calling just a normal function you don't necessarily need to use the `call` effect. Saga's yield can handle promises directly. So you can do just:

```js
const date = yield cloudfy.requestExtractList({ DadosConta, })
```